# XSLT 1.0 Does altova xmlspy built in xslt-engine does not have node-set function?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi i am using an external named template in my xslt that tokenize a string and store it in a variable.
I am using Altova XML SPY and i am restricted to xslt 1.0. The Problem is each time i have to change option from Built-in XSLT engine to Microsoft. 
Is there any node-set function or some other function instead of node-set in built-in xslt engine

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:import href="tokenize.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/string/upara">

        <xsl:variable name="string">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="/string/upara"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>



<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($string)/word">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)" />
</xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML i am using is

```
<string>
 <upara>This is a small string </upara>
 </string>
```

The string variable have all the words nodes like this

```
 <string>
 <word>This</word>
 <word>is</word>
```

Now i have to iterate over each word and find its length

Please tell me if there is any better way to do it.

I got this working

Sorry i am new to XSLT 1.0 and got confused.
Instead of using node-set I simply used

```
<xsl:for-each select="$string/word">
xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)" />
<br></br>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It works Perfect without changing engine :) :D

Answer (score 0):

XML Spy has a habit of treating result tree fragments (RTF) as if they were nodesets. I can't find any documentation that states this directly, but it is something you will find.

Any xsl command that returns a (RTF) and is stored in a variable, can be queried as if it were a node-set, for example by using `xsl:value-of`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837589/result-tree-fragment-to-node-set-generic-approach-for-all-xsl-engines), has a few XSLT-engine non-specific appraches that may be worth looking at.