# Show an element value from a variable in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I select a specific element from a variable in XSLT 1.0? 
I can see all of the elements by using `<xsl:copy-of select="$foo"/>` but what if I would only want a value from one element within the variable?

Comment: That depends exactly what your variable contains and how it is defined.  Can you show the `<xsl:variable>` definition?  Are you setting it with a `select="..."` or with nested children?

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to address the element that you want.

For instance:

```
$foo/bar
```

A more complete answer could be provided if you posted sample XML, showed how you are assigning the `$foo` variable, and which element value you are trying to address.

Comment: Here is the variable `<xsl:variable name ="Test">
        <el id ="5">foo5</el>
        <el id ="6">foo6</el>
    </xsl:variable>` When I do this `<xsl:value-of select="$Test/el[@id='6']" />` It does not work.

Comment: That's a limitation in xslt 1.0. It does work if you assign something from the source document to the variable Test (using the `select` attribute) but not if you assign it with xml from the .xslt file directly.Technically that's because the former is a node-set and the latter is a result-tree fragment. Check this question out if you want to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837589/result-tree-fragment-to-node-set-generic-approach-for-all-xsl-engines